# Изменение свойств в одной таблице, при изменении количества свойства в другой

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос, select

Я в работе с базами новичек и вот с чем не могу разобраться
Заголовок наверно не правильно составил, но суть такая

есть таблица заказов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в ней есть столбец idCake - id тортика который заказали, так же в ней есть столбец confirm, так вот когда на фронте нажимаю кнопку 'подтвердить заказ' я меняю 0 на 1 и запускаю ф-цию которая делает запрос в таблицу 2 в которой есть поля с id тортика и id ингредиентов входящих в состав тортика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге у меня есть массив из объектов
я так понимаю будет что то типа
[{id:1, quantity200}, {id:2, quantity2}]
 - сколько нужно ингредиентов списать из таблицы 3 (склад)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот возникло 2 вопроса - по правильной логике я строию работу бэка и как правильнее списать ингридиенты со склада ( просто пустить массив в цикл и делать много маленьких запросов или нужно сделать один большой запрос?)

Comment: Что значит `Weght` в таблице заказов?

Comment: @Alex78191 вес тортика - нужно еще quantity ингредиента умножать на вес тортика

Comment: @Alex78191 можно и так сделать - но я бы хотел понять именно как правильно делать такие вещи

Comment: @ГошкаТарас наверное был неправ

Answer (score 0):

Можно как-то так

```
UPDATE Ингридиент as ingr
SET quantity = quantity -  (SELECT quantity * Weight FROM Торт WHERE idCake = {{cakeId}} AND idIngr = ingr.id)
WHERE idIngr IN (SELECT idIngr from Торт WHERE idCake = {{cakeId}})
```

Или можно объединить таблицы `Ингридиент` и `Торт` вместо подзапросов

```
UPDATE Ингридиент as I
INNER JOIN ( SELECT quantity * Weight FROM Торт
             WHERE idCake = {{cakeId}} ) as T ON I.idIngr = T.idIngr
SET I.quantity = I.quantity - T.quantity
```

Не тестировал код на работоспособность.

Answer (score 0):

Даже на самом непримечательном железе 1000 запросов к БД отработаются так, как будто ничего и не было. Не думаю, что сайт с производством тортиков будет иметь 100к хитов в сутки. Я бы сделал 2 запроса: 1 к таблице заказов, для подтверждения, 2 для списания продуктов. Плюс ко всему, если подтверждение будет идти из админки, то думать об этом не нужно вовсе, ибо 100 таких хитов БД даже не почувствует.